# how to find duplicate records in mongo db query to use

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have below collection, need to find duplicate records in mongo, how can we find that as below is one sample of collection we have around more then 10000 records of collections.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1814099,
    "eventId" : "LAS012",
    "eventName" : "CustomerTab",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2018-12-31T20:09:09.820Z"),
    "eventMethod" : "click",
    "resourceName" : "CustomerTab",
    "targetType" : "",
    "resourseUrl" : "",
    "operationName" : "",
    "functionStatus" : "",
    "results" : "",
    "pageId" : "CustomerPage",
    "ban" : "290824901",
    "jobId" : "87377713",
    "wrid" : "87377713",
    "jobType" : "IBJ7FXXS",
    "Uid" : "sc343x",
    "techRegion" : "W",
    "mgmtReportingFunction" : "N",
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: which key can be used to check the uniqueness ?

Comment: eventId  field having duplicates values in collection.

Answer (score 3):

We can first find the `unique ids` using

```
const data = await db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$eventId",
      id: {
        "$first": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      uniqueIds: {
        $push: "$id"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

And then we can make another query, which will find all the `duplicate documents`

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$nin: data.uniqueIds}})
```

This will find all the documents that are redundant.

---

**Another way**
To find the event ids which are duplicated

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {"$group" : { "_id": "$eventId", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }
)
```

Comment: any way to directly find duplicates records.

Comment: I have added another way to find the `eventIds` for which there are more than 1 documents

Comment: does this answer your query?

Answer (score 0):

To get duplicates from db, you need to get only the groups that have a count of more than one, we can use the $match operator to filter our results. Within the $match pipeline operator, we'll tell it to look at the count field and tell it to look for counts greater than one using the $gt operator representing "greater than" and the number 1. This looks like the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group: {
    _id: {eventId: "$eventId"},
    uniqueIds: {$addToSet: "$_id"},
    count: {$sum: 1}
    }
},
{$match: { 
    count: {"$gt": 1}
    }
}
]);
```

I assume that eventId is a unique id.